# Is there an idiom that means "offering little resistance" as in a negotiation, physical fight, war?

Tags: idiom-request

I am looking for an idiom that means "offering little resistance" in a very general way such that it can be used in the context of a negotiation, physical fight or even war. Is there such an idiom? If "offering little resistance" is too specific, try something like "being weak", which has a similar meaning.

Comment: Have you looked up synonyms for "wimp", "wuss", "pushover", and "loser"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say *it was a* [***piece of cake***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piece%20of%20cake):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : something easily done : CINCH, BREEZE

So, for example:

> Fighting him was a *piece of cake*.